# What pH ranges are used in industrial scale fermentation?

Tags: biotechnology, fermentation, ph

When reading

> Hans-Peter Meyer, Wolfgang Minas, and Diego Schmidhalter (2017) **Industrial-Scale Fermentation**. Industrial Biotechnology: Products and Processes, First Edition. Edited by Christoph Wittmann and James C. Liao.
>   © 2017 Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH & Co. KGaA. Published 2017 by Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH & Co. KGaA.

I came across the following passage describing industrial up-scaling of fermentation processes (in general):

> ### 1.3.1
>
> ### Process Development – Scale-Up Starts at Laboratory Scale
>
> Process scale-up should be considered early on while the biological expression
>   system is still under development. Factors such as genetic stability for at least
>   the number of generations needed for a scaled-up production, and the need and
>   impact on the environment of selection markers, should be evaluated before
>   process development is started. The use of antibiotics as selective markers in the
>   production medium should be avoided. Throughout development of media and
>   cultivation conditions, it is important that parameter settings remain realistic and
>   scalable, always indicated with upper and lower limits reflecting the safe operating
>   range (process design space), **for example, pH 7 ± 0.3.**

I am quite surprised about the narrow pH range specified (pH $7 \pm 0.3$). I assumed that the pH range would be much wider, similar to lab scale. Is this really common practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermentation pH will differ a great deal depending on the bacteria or fungi being used and the process. But it is not uncommon to have a relatively narrow range of pH as a target. Remember pH is the -log[H+] so the pH scale is not linear. Also some fermentation reaction involve very expensive pharmaceuticals or intermediates, a single fermentation batch may have a value in the hundreds of thousands of dollars so keeping +/- 0.3 range in pH is trivial.